# PHP Sign in form does not show alert boxes

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a sign in form with PHP for my site. Basically what I did was to write some codes that if a user does not enter username or password a message must pop up on the page to notice him:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['sign_in'])){
        if(empty($_POST['uname'])){
            echo "<script>alert('Username must be entered')</script>";
        }else{
            $uname = $_POST['uname'];
            if(empty($_POST['pass'])){
                echo "<script>alert('Password must be entered')</script>";
            }else{
                $pass = $_POST['pass'];
                $select = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname = '$uname' AND pass = '$pass'");
                $select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $select->execute();
                $data = $select->fetch();
                if($data['uname'] != $uname AND $data['pass'] != $pass){
                    echo "<script>alert('Username or passsword is wrong')</script>";
                }elseif($data['uname'] == $uname AND $data['pass'] == $pass){
                    $_SESSION['uname'] = $data['uname'];
                    $_SESSION['pass'] = $data['pass'];
                    echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' Content='0; URL=profile.php?username=$uname'>";
                }else{
                    echo "<script>alert('Try again')</script>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['login_insta'])){
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL='.$instagram->getLoginURL().'">';
    }
?>
```

But whenever I leave a field empty to check these codes, the page redirects without showing any message.

So what is wrong with this?

Comment: What is the name of this script

Comment: **Warning:** You're currently not using prepared statements correctly. You should use placeholders in the query instead of injecting completely unescaped user data into it. [Read more here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: **Warning:** Never store passwords in clear text! Create a hash of the password using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and only store the hash. Then you use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: Is it PDO or MySQLi?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be specifically MySQL it PDO related

Comment: Here can have `html` codes that is not formatted correctly. You can right click on the browser and open `inspect element`. I hope you will be able to see any javascript error in `console`.